# Minecraft inventory glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I am on the latest version of Minecraft 1.14.4
I know that in the past version of Minecraft when using the inventory and moving items you can click and hold and just run your mouse over all the items to move them into a chest or into your inventory. Now I have to click each individual item in order to move it into my inventory. Is this a glitch or did they genuinely take that part of the programming out?
Please help, I have tried re-installing my game, and restarting it.
In the modded versions of minecraft it works for me, but in the classic vanilla, it doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean moving multiple stacks of items from your inventory into a chest or back with one mouse movement: That was never in the game, only mods added that.

Comment: oh thank you, I never realized that. I'm so used to playing with mods

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if you think it’s correct